# Trigger.io and TestFlight rejects ipa with "must have get-task-allow set to true"

Tags: ios, trigger.io, testflight

I am building my iOS app with trigger.io, using an ad-hoc distribution profile created by my organization. I can build the app with no warnings or errors, but when I upload it to TestFlight I get the following error:

```
Invalid Profile: developer build entitlements must have get-task-allow set to true.
```

I looked at the distribution profile in a text editor and it is, in fact, set to false:

```
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
```

What's the best way to debug this? Is there any documentation that describes how to correctly configure all three services to work together (Apple Developer Site, Trigger.io, and TestFlight)? Thanks!